# How to get the path to the currently included cmake file in a function?

Tags: cmake

suppose I have this:

```
#root/CMakeLists.txt
include(folder/file.cmake)
foo()
```

and

```
#root/folder/file.cmake
function(foo)
    message(${SOME_SPECIAL_CMAKE_VARIABLE})
endfunction()
```

And I want to get `path/to/root/folder` printed.
I tried these 2 but they don't get me what I want: `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` or `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`.

So is there a cmake variable that will get me what I want?

Or is there a way to get the full path to `file.cmake` so I can atleast get it's path that way?

Comment: Why is `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` not suitable for your needs? For a fresh enough CMake (>=2.8.3) it contains the required info.

Comment: @user3159253 hmmm actually using it in a function inside ```file.cmake``` was returning the wrong result - but when I printed it like I've said here it worked fine. So maybe I should cache it in some variable the first time ```file.cmake``` is included and then use the cached value inside the function?

Comment: @onqtam You should really [edit] the question to make it clear you're referring to "inside a function defined in a file" and not to "inside a file." They're quite different things. Anyway, storing the value in a variable and using that is pretty much what CMake itself does in its own build setup.

Comment: @Angew I didn't understand the part about the build setup of cmake - Isn't the solution I proposed the only way?

Comment: @onqtam It could very well be the only way. What I meant is: CMake itself is solving the same (or similar) issue in its own build, and is solving it in exactly the way you describe: it saves the value of the "dynamic variable" in a normal variable for later use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake 3.17 introduced a new variable for just this case: [CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR.html). Used inside a CMake function this evaluates to absolute path of the file in which the function is defined.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up caching the `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` variable when the file is included outside of the function and later I use the cached value inside the function - based on the comments of my question.